# Are all highly composite numbers greater than or equal to 12 divisible by 12? How could this be proven?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Highly composite numbers are positive integers with more factors than all smaller positive integers. I noticed, looking through [the OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A002182), that all the numbers listed that were greater than or equal to twelve were divisible by it. I haven't really seen this talked about before anywhere. Is this true, and if so why?

Comment: As [Wikipedia notes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number#Prime_factorization), the prime factorization of a highly composite number with $k$ distinct prime factors must consists of the first $k$ primes, and the exponents must be nondecreasing. Checking that past $4$, squarefree integers and powers of $2$ don’t work gives the result.

Answer (score 3):

The prime factorization of a number $k$ is an increasing sequence of primes $p_1, p_2, ... p_n$, together with a sequence of positive integers $e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$, such that $k = \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n p_j^{e_j}$. Every positive integer has a unique prime factorization.

Note that the number of factors of $k$ (which I denote $f(k)$) is given by $\prod\limits_{j = 1}^n (e_j + 1)$. Interestingly, the number of factors depends only on the powers $e_1, ..., e_n$ and not at all on which primes are used.

This has some important consequences for highly composite numbers. In particular, if $k$ is a highly composite number, it must be the case that $p_1, .., p_n$ is a sequence of consecutive primes starting with 2 (for if there is a prime $q$ between $p_j$ and $p_{j + 1}$, simply replace $p_{j + 1}$ by $q$ to get a smaller number with the same number of factors, and if $p_1$ is not $2$, replace $p_1$ by $2$). It must also be the case that the sequence $e_k$ must be decreasing (for if $e_j < e_{j + 1}$, simply swap the two to get a smaller number with the same number of factors).

What sorts of highly composite numbers are there without 12 as a factor?

Case 1: Those that do not have 3 as a factor. In that case, they must be a power of 2 (that is, $k = 2^m$). Then the number of factors will be $m + 1$. But if $m \geq 3$, then we have $2^{m - 2} \cdot 3 < 2^{m - 2} \cdot 4 = 2^m$, and the number of factors of $2^{m - 2} \cdot 3$ will be $2(m - 1) = 2m - 2 = (m + 1) + (m - 3) \geq m + 1$. Thus, $2^m$ is not hypercomposite for $m \geq 3$, so the only hypercomposite numbers of this class are 1, 2, and 4, all of which are smaller than 12.

Case 2: those that have 3 as a factor but not 4. These must be of the form $\prod\limits_{j = 1}^n p_j$, where $n \geq 2$.

Case 2a: $n = 2$. Then the number is $6 < 12$.

Case 2b: $n \geq 3$. Then the number is $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \prod\limits_{j = 4}^n p_j$. This number has $2^n$ prime factors. But it is greater than $8 \cdot 3 \cdot \prod\limits_{j = 4}^n p_j$, which also has $2^n$ factors. So there is no hypercomposite number of this form.

Thus, all hypercomposite numbers at least 12 have 12 as a factor.